# how to create listener and multiple channel of queuemanager and display status in mq?

Tags: ibm-mq

`echo "display chstatus(qm.apple.qm.orange) | runmqsc $qm.apple"`

I try this above command in mq but it needs two queue manager name to display the status whether it is running or retrying condition. But What I Actually need is to display what are all the channel are in the one queue manager.

I need to give one queue manager name. with that name it should display all the channel in queue manager.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to just get a list of all the Channels in a Queue Manager you could execute:
`echo "DISPLAY CHANNEL(*)" | runmqsc <QM Name>`
However, this will return *all* of the Channels on the Queue Manager including the MQ system channels.

To create a listener on a Queue Manager you can use the `DEFINE LISTENER` runmqsc command. This command takes two parameters, the name of the listener and the type of the listener. You should also tell the listener what port to listen on. For example:

`DEFINE LISTENER('LISTEN.TCP') TRPTYPE(TCP) PORT(1234)`

Once you have created a listener you must start the listener in order for it to actively listen for connections. You start a listener using the `START LISTENER` runmqsc command. (Note: In order to successfully start a listener, the port it has been told to listen on must be available to bind to. i.e. no other application must be using that port):

`START LISTENER('LISTEN.TCP')`

Comment: how to create listener and multiple channel for this queue manager?   The above command is works fine.. But I need to create multiple channel for this queue manager. because when i create a channel it requires two queue manager name...Is there any command to create channel for single queuemanger .....

Comment: I'll expand the question to detail how to create a listener. But could you elaborate what you mean about what channel type you are creating that requires two Queue Manager names? Could you show me an example of the command creating the channel labelling the two queue manager names?